# Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches)

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

**Scenario**
I  have a category class in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [pk_cat_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [parent_cat_id] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_cat_id] ASC
))
```

[image]

Category class has association to itself. It is a recursive, bidirectional association(many-to-one and one-to-many).
Both refer to the same foreign key column: parent_cat_id.
A category can have one parent at-most and no or more child categories.

This is Category.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns ="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly ="NHibernateIntro.Core"
                   namespace ="NHibernateIntro.Core.Domain">

  <class name="Category" table="Category">

    <id name="CategoryId" column="pk_cat_id">
      <generator class="hilo"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="name" type="string" length="50" not-null="true" />

    <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="Category" column="parent_cat_id" />

    <bag name="childCategories" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="parent_cat_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Category"/>      
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is Category.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

namespace NHibernateIntro.Core.Domain
{
    public class Category
    {
        private Category parent_category;
        private ISet<Category> child_Categories = new HashedSet<Category>();

        public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public Category() { }

        public Category( string cat_name )
        {
            Name = cat_name;
        }

        public virtual Category ParentCategory 
        {
            get
            {
                if (parent_category == null)
                    parent_category = new Category();

                return parent_category;
            }
            set{ parent_category = value; }
        }

        public virtual ISet<Category> childCategories
        {
            get { return child_Categories; }
            set { child_Categories = value; }
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the Main method:

```
public static void Run(ISessionFactory factory)
{
    int computerId = 1;

    using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
    using (session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Category computer = session.Get<Category>(computerId); // **This line causes   Error(stated below)**
// Please see 'CONFUSING' tag below.
            Category laptops = new Category("Laptops");
            computer.childCategories.Add(laptops);
            laptops.ParentCategory = computer;
            session.Save(laptops);
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

**CONFUSING** : When i debugged the code it stuck here at this line: "set{ parent_category = value; }". I am confused because I am assigning to Cateory then why setter of parentCategory is being called here?

**Error:**
Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches);
 setter of NHibernateIntro.Core.Domain.Category

*Inner Error:* Unable to cast object of type'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[NHibernateIntro.Core.Domain.Category]'
to type 'Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[NHibernateIntro.Core.Domain.Category]'.

kINDLY hELP!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *set* in the mapping file instead of bag. Because  ISet cannot be casted to IList and bag mapping is compatible with a .NET IList

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
private ISet<Category> child_Categories = new HashedSet<Category>();
```

to

```
private ICollection<Category> child_Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
```

and it should work. Note that I'm using the C# HashSet, not the Iesi.Collections HashedSet. More recent versions of NHibernate may support HashSet directly.

Comment: Yup.. Thats fine too. Now i am having one more problem at: session.Transaction.Commit(); Error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: You may want to ask that in another question. Your ParentCategory getter is newing up a parent category that isn't saved explicitly and I don't think it will be saved by cascade. I would not do this in the getter, you should new it up somewhere else.

Comment: But I think that could be saved by cascade, but the problem is: Due to self referencing, 'ParentCategory' will try to save its parent and that would (take forever) occur recursively and eventually result in StackOverFlow error. Besides,  also learnt that self referencing is not very good practice.However, It is good if you are inserting few records.